# How do I properly change radio button labels with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

I'm using jQuery 3.5.1.  I have this HTML

```
<form>
    <div><input type="radio" id="radio0" name="choice" >Text1</div>
    <div><input type="radio" id="radio1" name="choice" >Text2</div>
    <div><input type="radio" id="radio2" name="choice" >Text3</div>
    <div><input type="radio" id="radio3" name="choice" >Text4</div>
```

I want to change the labels next to the radio buttons, so I do this ...

```
for (let i=0; i<choices.length; i++) {
    $('#radio' + i).text(choices[i]);
    $('#radio' + i).val(choices[i] == age ? CORRECT : INCORRECT);
    $('#radio' + i).attr("checked", false);
}
```

However, the new labels do not appear on screen.  When I inspect the elemnts in Firefox (on Mac), I see this

```
<div><input type="radio" id="radio0" name="choice" value="incorrect">27
Text1</div>
<div><input type="radio" id="radio1" name="choice" value="incorrect">24
Text2</div>
<div><input type="radio" id="radio2" name="choice" value="incorrect">21
Text3</div>
<div><input type="radio" id="radio3" name="choice" value="correct">30
Text4</div>
<div id="feedback" style="display: none;"></div>
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitAnswer">
</div>
```

So somehow the elements are getting populated (the "27", "24", etc.) but the old elements are also still there ("Text1") and what appears on screen is the "Text-" labels instead of the numbers.  What's the right way to structure the HTML/write the jQuery to change the radio button labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Radios are far easier to use when wrapped in `<label>` since the whole label is target for events.

Then if you add a `<span>` to wrap the text it becomes an easy target for DOM queries

```js
const newVals = [111, 444, 777, 999]

newVals.forEach((v, i) => {
  const $input = $('#radio' + i).val(v).prop('checked', false);
  $input.next('span').text(v);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio0" name="choice" >
    <span>Text1</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div><label><input type="radio" id="radio1" name="choice" ><span>Text2</span></label></div>
<div><label><input type="radio" id="radio2" name="choice" ><span>Text3</span></label></div>
<div><label><input type="radio" id="radio3" name="choice" ><span>Text4</span></label></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using labels for the strings?

```
<div><input type="radio" id="radio0" name="choice" ><label id="label0">Text1</label></div>
```

Then you can do this?

```
for (let i=0; i<choices.length; i++) {
    $('#label' + i).text(choices[i]);
    $('#radio' + i).val(choices[i] == age ? CORRECT : INCORRECT);
    $('#radio' + i).attr("checked", false);
}
```

Comment: For label to interact with radio checking should either wrap input or add a `for`